prevent renderedCallBack from resetting to initial value
I am working on pagination using lwc component. There is a  variable clickedPage =1. In the UI on clicking page 2, handleClick method updates clickedPage as 2 but then the renderedCallBack resets the value back to 1 and page 1 remains highlighted instead of 2.
How do I prevent this? Below is my code:
renderedCallback() {
    this.changeColorOnClick();
}

changeColorOnClick() {
    this.template.querySelectorAll("lightning-button").forEach((e) => {
        if (Number(e.label) === this.clickedPage) {
            e.classList.add("currentpage");
            e.blur();
        } else {
            e.classList.remove("currentpage");
        }
    }
);


Please edit your question to include the relevant code.  We can guess what you're doing, but it's hard to be certain.

The renderedcallback() method is called whenever there's a change to the state of your LWC.  Changing the value of clickedPage will result in renderedCallback being triggered.
Without knowing your code, you need to stop renderedCallback from setting clickedPage.  There are two ways to do this:

add some logic to renderedCallback to not perform this update if it's already initialized
move the logic that sets clickedPage somewhere else, probably connectedCallback

I'm guess you're just trying to initialize clickedPage, so just move it to connectedCallback
See docs:  https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/lwc/guide/create-lifecycle-hooks-rendered.html

After a component is connected and rendered, any changes or mutations to its state trigger the rerendering process:

The component gets marked as "dirty."
A microtask rerender the component gets enqueued.


